# How do you make a custom XAML User Control bindable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a simple demo to learn how to create a bindable user control. I have created a simple class:

```
class Person
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;    
    public Person(string first, string last)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }
}
```

And a very simple user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.ExampleHRControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textFirstName"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textLastName"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I would like to know is what do I need to do in order to be able to use the user control in context like a normal control. I can add this to the `MainWindow`:

```
<local:ExampleHRControl x:Name="Hr1"></local:ExampleHRControl>
```

and then I can address it through code behind and add the value:

```
Hr1.textFirstName.Text = "John";
Hr1.textLasttName.Text = "Doe";
```

I would prefer to be able to create an instance of the class `Person` and simply bind the control on the main window to the `Person` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple things you need to do to make this work.

In your code-behind, add a dependency property for the Person object you want your control to know about:

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonProperty =
                          DependencyProperty.Register("Person", typeof(Person),
                                                      typeof(ExampleHRControl));

   public Person Person
   {
      get { return (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty); }
      set { SetValue(PersonProperty, value); }
   }
```

In your XAML, set up your code-behind as your data context and add the binding to your person object:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.ExampleHRControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="This">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="{Binding Path=Person.FirstName, ElementName=This}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="{Binding Path=Person.LastName, ElementName=This}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, whenever the Person property is set, your control will update itself with the First and Last names that are associated to the Person.

Comment: It may be beneficial to not change the `DataContext`, especially if this `UserControl` ends up being a `ContentControl`. A simple solution to this would be to name the user control and reference it in the bindings via `ElementName`.

Comment: sixlettervariables is right. Take a look at this [explanation](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/) for the reason.

Comment: I have made the change that sixlettervariables recommended in my original posting above.

Answer (score 2):

what you want to to called Dependancy Property you can bind to it from xaml. 
1-create the field

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FirstName", typeof(Strin),
```

2-create the property

```
public String FirstName
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
}
```

3- you can use it in the XAML to bind it or just use it

```
<local:YourControlName FirstName="john"/>

<local:YourControlName FirstName="{Binding MyFirstName}"/>
```

- use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will help you to make a clean code and have very powerfull IntelliSense

Comment: thank you, that looks like what I was missing.  I will work on putting that together.

Comment: one other question if I can -- can I bind the whole control rather than just a single property?